# Xcode Swift2: Can't get callstack for fatal error

Tags: ios, swift, debugging, xcode7, option-type

Swift2 / iOS9 / XCode 7.0.1

I see the following output in the console:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

I can't get a callstack to track down where this is coming from. I've enabled the "All Exceptions" breakpoint, but it doesn't get hit. I think this is because the error is due to a timing / threading issue because ***I only see it when I hit another breakpoint***, it doesn't occur during a normal application run. I'm guessing that because Xcode is already on a breakpoint, and the error is occurring on a different thread, then the `All Exceptions` breakpoint doesn't trigger.

How can I get a callstack for this error message?

Comment: I tried putting an `NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(1)` in place of the other breakpoint to see if I could get the error during a normal run but it still didn't happen.

Comment: I have my suspicions that the messages may be caused by Xcode's Debug Area trying to unwrap optionals under the `self` auto.